# Unable to delete any rows from a table

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We have a MySQL 5.5 Amazon EC2 instance (db.m1.small) which shows "storage full" in the status column of the Amazon RDS console.

We tried connecting via SQL and removing a bunch of rows, but the delete command hangs. How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably increase the storage space and try the commands again, maybe its unable to delete since its storage is full.